# Toyota RAV4 2010 2.2 diesel

Tags: engine

Hi my RAV4 revs up through the 3000 revs fast when cold but when it is warm it stutters after 3000 if pushed fast

Comment: Have you had the codes checked? Have you had the injectors tested? spray pattern, leakoff etc

Comment: What do you mean by "revs fast"?

Comment: If I excelarate fast when cold it goes up through the revs ok when cold but when warm stutters at 3000 upwards

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I used to own a silimar vehicle. The engine in that vehicle is the 2AD-FTV engine. My suggestion is to get an OBD-II reader and read live data from it. Check your fuel rail pressure while you reproduce the problem. What I suspect you will see is a sharp drop in FRP when it stutters.

Fuel rail pressure issues would be one of three things.

1. At the end of the fuel manifold/rail there is a pressure release valve, that allows fuel to go back to the tank. I don't think it is this, but that is one possibility.
2. On the fuel pump there is something called an SCV, a suction control valve. Especially early AD engines are known to have SCV problems.
3. The fuel pump itself. This is the most expensive one to repair. I also don't think this is the issue, since it only happens when the vehicle is hot.

If it does turn out to be the SCV, it could be that the SCV itself is sticking when warm, or it could be that the ECU is not controlling it properly. To really test the latter, you'll need an oscilloscope to look at the PWM signal that controls the SCV. You may want to leave this to a professional.